# Maven not finding dependencies in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, javafx, dependencies, maven-plugin

I'm new to Maven and not quite sure what it's for but I thought it was for importing external libraries so that they are available while coding. I have imported the dependency and there's no error on it as can be seen here:

[image]

But when typing the import it all just comes up in red as if it's not found. It's not finding anything.

[image]

And if I paste the whole import line in it gets deleted automatically.

Is this not what Maven is supposed to do or is there something else to do before it will work? I also have it set to *import Maven projects automatically*.

EDIT: Just for clarity, of course it's in my `pom.xml` file otherwise it wouldn't be showing up in the external libraries in the screenshot above:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>uk.co.caprica</groupId>
        <artifactId>vlcj</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>uk.co.caprica</groupId>
        <artifactId>vlcj-javafx</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Additional EDIT: Some screenshots to show that typing the classes directly does not work any better. Intellij is just not finding anything:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems this particular dependency is modularised per the [*Java Platform Module System*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System). So, we need `requires` in the `module-info.java` file.

```
module com.sample {
    requires javafx.controls;
    exports com.sample;
    requires transitive javafx.graphics;
    requires uk.co.caprica.vlcj;
    requires uk.co.caprica.vlcj.javafx;
}
```

After this the dependency is suddenly visible and fully usable within the code.

Comment: "_It seems this particular dependency is modularised_" – Just want to point out that is not necessarily the important part. The important part is that **your code** is modularized. Your module must declare a `requires` directive for **every** dependency it uses. Even if a dependency was not a proper module (i.e. has no module-info descriptor) your module would still need to `requires` it (since it's not a module it becomes an "automatic module").

Comment: @Slaw Since it's a default JavaFX project I didn't think there would be anything strange about it. I assumed it must be something up with the dependency since that is the only unique thing about the project.

Comment: Understandable. My comment is only meant to provide more information (for you or any future readers) about _why_ you had to declare a `requires` directive. You were correct that the problem was regarding the dependency; it's just that JPMS modules and dependencies are closely related.

Comment: @Slaw Still no idea why since it was a default project. I used the standard default project so that's why nobody had any idea it would be like this? Very odd.